# Why does prism.js modify the DOM by inserting the language class into a surrounding <pre> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, prism.js

When I have code nested like this (taken straight from prism's front page), the pre tag also gets the `language-css` class when I inspect the DOM in my browser. Here is the code as I've written it:

```
<pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
```

When I inspect it in the browser it is like this:

```
<pre class="language-css"><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
```

My example is slightly different (different language than CSS), but the structure of elements is very close for me `<pre><code/><textarea/></pre>`

If I either 1) remove the prism.js line in my index.html (thus removing prism.js functionality) or 2) remove the class from the `<code>` tag (also removing the functionality for this example) the `<pre>` tag will no longer have `language-css` when I inspect it in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the class to both elements allows theme authors to distinguish between code blocks (`<pre><code>`) and inline code (`<p><code>`). For example, the default Prism theme contains these three rules:

```css
/* Code blocks */
pre[class*="language-"] {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

:not(pre) > code[class*="language-"],
pre[class*="language-"] {
    background: #f5f2f0;
}

/* Inline code */
:not(pre) > code[class*="language-"] {
    padding: .1em;
    border-radius: .3em;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

As a use case, some theme authors may want to apply different styles to code blocks based on their language. For example, on my site (in places such as the [About page](https://novalistic.com/about)), I've added labels to my code blocks using generated content — this can be added to the default theme like so:

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.14.0/themes/prism.min.css');

pre[class*="language-"] {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2.5em;
}

pre[class*="language-"]::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
}

pre.language-html::before { content: 'HTML'; }
pre.language-css::before { content: 'CSS'; }
```

```html
<pre><code class="language-html">&lt;!DOCTYPE html>
&lt;title>HTML&lt;/title>
&lt;p>Prism example</code></pre>

<pre><code class="language-css">pre[class*="language-"] {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}

pre[class*="language-"]::before {
  display: block;
  font: 0.8em sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}

pre.language-html::before { content: 'HTML'; }
pre.language-css::before { content: 'CSS'; }</code></pre>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.14.0/prism.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.14.0/components/prism-markup.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.14.0/components/prism-css.min.js"></script>
```